# Remove timezone information from datetime object

Tags: python

What is the fastest way to trim datetime object of this form `2016-12-14 15:57:16.140645` to become like this: `2016-12-14 15:57:16`? doing `str('2016-12-14 15:57:16.140645').strip(".")[0]` is painfully slow for large datasets and besides I need the returned format to be a datetime object

Comment: The `140645` part isn't timezone info, it's the microseconds value of the datetime object. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: If the string ends with 'dot' then 6 digits try `myString[:-7]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use `strftime` if you already have a datetime object

```
dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

If you need a datetime object from a string, the fastest way is to use strptime and a slice:

```
st = '2016-12-14 15:57:16.140645'
dt = datetime.strptime(st[:19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: If you are slicing, you might as well do it right

`dt = datetime.strptime(st[:st.rfind('.')], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 52):

For those that came here for the actual question 'Remove timezone information from datetime object', the answer would be something like:
`datetimeObject.replace(tzinfo=None)`

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import time

datetimeObject = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time(), timezone.utc)
print(datetimeObject)
datetimeObject = datetimeObject.replace(tzinfo=None)
print(datetimeObject)
```

Comment: I have `datetime64[ns, Asia/Kolkata]` object. I tried `dt[["ts"]].replace(tzinfo=None)`. It is giving me an error saying `TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tzinfo'`. Could you please suggest?

Comment: Is `dt[["ts"]]` a pandas Dataframe? I would assume that the Dataframe object has the method replace, which is obviously different to the datetime replace method. You may want to look at Pandas 'apply' and go from there.

Comment: Incorrect. This does work with a Python datetime object.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71095769/16733101